# Find specific customer type from listbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to ask about my work.

I have to find specific customer types which are `adult, child,concession` from `listbox customer type`.

Here is my code :

```
    Dim iCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim sCustType As String = ""

    sCustType = "adult" Or "child" Or "concession"


    For iCounter = 0 To lstCustType.Items.Count + 1

        If lstCustType.Items(iCounter) = sCustType Then

            lstQuoteResult.Items.Add(lstQuoteNum.Items(iCounter))
            lstCustResult.Items.Add(lstCustType.Items(iCounter))
            lstBagResult.Items.Add(lstBaggageWeight.Items(iCounter))
            lstBagWeightResult.Items.Add(lstBagWeight.Items(iCounter))
            lstDestResult.Items.Add(lstDestinationCost.Items(iCounter))
            lstTripResult.Items.Add(lstHighSesason.Items(iCounter))
            lstQuiteResult.Items.Add(lstQuiteCarriageCost.Items(iCounter))
            lstInsResult.Items.Add(lstInsurance.Items(iCounter))
            lstInsCResult.Items.Add(lstInsuraneCost.Items(iCounter))
            lstReturnResult.Items.Add(lstReturnTripCost.Items(iCounter))
            lstTotalResult.Items.Add(lstTotal.Items(iCounter))
        End If
    Next
```

But it does not work. Apparently there is an error said `Conversion from string "adult" to type 'Long' is not valid.`

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding .ToString during your item comparison:

```
If lstCustType.Items(iCounter).ToString() = sCustType Then
```

Also, your loop will throw an error as you should be stepping down 1 after the count, not up 1, since the listbox is indexed starting at 0. This would eventually throw an error as the listbox attempts to access an index that doesn't exist. Should read:

```
For iCounter = 0 To lstCustType.Items.Count - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> sCustType = "adult" Or "child" Or "concession"

Using the or operator like this, the compiler is expecting to preform a bitwise or on 2 longs.  You probably need to make a collection of customer types, then use LINQ to do a specific search of the items collections.